# Cron Jobs stopped working after upgrade to civi version 4.6.33

Tags: joomla, cron-job

I was happily running civi 4.6.30 on Joomla 3.8.3. (which was also upgraded automagically this week) with everything working fine when up came that security warning this week. I upgraded to 4.6.33 yesterday night without any errors, but after that cron jobs stopped working. I am running the wget method because everything else was simply not working the way it was described in cron docs.

Comment: Can you detail a bit more what is happening when you run the cron job from the cli? do you have an error message or something? What command do you run?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no mail or other output from the cli. I run the following command every half hour: wget -O /dev/null -q -t 1 'https://walk2him.com/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bin/cron.php?name=xxxxxx&pass=yyyyy&key=zzzzz&job=process_mailing'
at 05,35
This was the only option that worked as all other options suggested with civi cron  would not work